# How can I deserialize JSON to a simple Dictionary<string,object> to datagridview using only dynamics?

Tags: c#, .net, json, javascriptserializer

I have a simple key/value list in JSON from a webserver and need to put this data in a datagridview without any dll as JSON.Net. I found Count equals a three (array json) but I can´t extract it. Example:

```
        var json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://server.com/getMsg.aspx");
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var dictObj = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, dynamic>>(json);
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        for (int i = 0; i < dictObj["result"].Count; i++)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.Id = dictObj["result"].Value[i].id;
            p.Name = dictObj["result"].Value[i].name;
            p.Age = dictObj["result"].Value[i].age; 
            list.Add(p);
        }

        datagridView1.DataSource = list;
```

The downloaded json is presented below:

```
{"result": [                                                                
    {"id": "14", "name": "sdfsdfsdf", "age": "40" },
    {"id": "13", "name": "vfdgdg", "age": "50" },
    {"id": "12", "name": "grgetge","age": "60" } ] }
```

Comment: For starters, don't use the deprecated class `JavaScriptSerializer`. Even ASP.NET Web API uses Json.NET

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would try to create a class `RootObject` to carry your `Person` collection instance.

then use `serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>` to make it.

```
public class Person
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string age { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Person> result { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use `List<Person>` instead of `for loop` directly

```
var dictObj = serializer.Deserialize<RootObject>(json);
datagridView1.DataSource = dictObj.result;
```

**Note**

I would suggest you use [Json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) third-party library instead of `JavaScriptSerializer` because its performance will be better than `JavaScriptSerializer`

And it use very simple, use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` can Deserialize json to object.

```
var dictObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(Json);
datagridView1.DataSource = dictObj.result;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!